# xamarin.forms how to select all text on focus with Entry?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know the Xamarin.Android code, but how about Xamarin.IOS?

Xamarin.Android code:

```cs
public class CustomNumEntry : EntryRenderer
{
    public CustomNumEntry(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetPadding(10, 0, 0, 15);
            Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
            Control.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;


        }
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
            nativeEditText.SetSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Comment: Excellent! Thx for sharing it!

Answer (score 2):

for Xamarin iOS:

```cs
nativeTextField.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs eIos) =>
                   {
                      nativeTextField.PerformSelector(new Selector("selectAll"), null, 0.0f);
                   };
```

for Xamarin.Forms using custom renderer for iOS(which you are looking for):

```cs
public class CustomNumEntry : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);    
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var nativeTextField = (UITextField)Control;    
                nativeTextField.EditingDidBegin += (object sender, EventArgs eIos) =>
                {
                   nativeTextField.PerformSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("selectAll"), null, 0.0f);
                };                           
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks , @Vikas Singh. but --> Selector("selectAll")   get Error :A constructor that does not contain a single parameter

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890929/xamarin-entry-cursor-position-when-selecting-all-text):

```
private void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    myEntry.CursorPosition = 0;
    myEntry.SelectionLength = entryItem.Text.Length;
}
```

Example shows selection of all text on focused but you can do the same on demand too.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can implement it in method **`EditingStarted`**.Refer the following code

```
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class MyEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer,IUITextFieldDelegate
  {
    public MyEntryRenderer()
    {


    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.WeakDelegate = this;   

        }

    }


    [Export("textFieldDidBeginEditing:")]
    public void EditingStarted(UITextField textField)
    {
        textField.PerformSelector(new Selector("selectAll:"), null, 0.0f);
    }

  }
}
```