# Xamarin Entry Cursor Position when Selecting All Text

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When my entry control is focused I select all text. When the text exceeds the width of the entry control the beginning of the text is truncated - as shown in the following image:

[Beginning truncated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5EfQ.png)

However, I want the tail to be truncated, like so:

[Tail truncated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naqzn.png)

`<Entry x:Name="entryA" Focused="entry_Focused"/>`

```
private void entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    entryA.CursorPosition = 0;
    entryA.SelectionLength = entryItem.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: Xamarin simply tells the native (android or ios) widget what the selection is. Looking at Android docs, I don't see any way to control this behavior under Android. I suspect iOS text boxes likewise lack this. (Though I did not look.) If ios or android do have some way to accomplish this, then the answer would be to write a "custom renderer" on each platform, to set such an option. Maybe someone else can find a way to do this, on the individual platforms. But I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

By using the **PropertyChanged** method of Entry, you can operate when the data in the data frame changes.

I wrote a small example for your reference：

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="entryA" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" PropertyChanged="entryA_PropertyChanged"></Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the background code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public int len { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void entryA_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var en = sender as Entry;
        if (en.Text != null && len != en.Text.Length) 
        {
            entryA.CursorPosition = 0;
            len = en.Text.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?